# How to create accessors and mutators if table column's name is uppercase

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using `Laravel` 4.2 in my project, how can I create `accessors` and `mutators` for my model, if database column's name pattern is like this:

```
| ABC_ID |  ABC_DAT_JAN | ABC_DAT_FEV | ABC_DAT_MAR | ABC_DAT_ABR |
| 1      |  12          | 10          | 20          | 13          |
```

I created the function `getAbcDatJanAttribute($value)`, but it's not working, expected, I think it try to get the attribute `abc_dat_jan`.

How can I create `accessors` abd `mutators` in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Laravel looks for `accessors` and `mutators` by converting the first letter of each word in the column name to uppercase and removing any `-` or `_`.

Since everything is uppercase for you, you can use `getABCDATJANAttribute($value)` instead.

Comment: I tried this way, but it's trying to get the attribute `a_bc_da_tj_an`, I know this no make sense, but I don't know why is working this way